# Number of elements in a sample space

Tags: probability

I am looking at the number of elements in the sample space and would like to confirm something please.

Using the fundamental counting principle, would it be right to say that the number of elements in the sample of **rolling a fair die twice and tossing a fair coin once** $= 6\times 6\times 2=72$?

Comment: Yes its correct. and by the way, the fair aspect isnt relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are the cartesian product of $$\{1,\ldots, 6\} \times \{1,\ldots, 6\} \times \{H,T\} $$

and the corresponding cardinaility is $6^2 \cdot (2)=72$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could be {1,1 1,2 ..... 6,6 , H} or {1,1 1,2 ..... 6,6 , T} so it's 72. This is assuming that Dice is rolled twice followed by a coin toss in the same order.